# Export Open Street Map and my Custom Tile Layer to PNG

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

I want to use Google Maps API, Open Street Map (map layer) and my own custom tile map layer and create a function to export the map to PNG.

I think this is allowed by Google's terms of service - as I am not using their copyrighted map layer. Am I right?

If this is allowed, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not a lawyer, I can't tell you anything about the legal aspect. You might consult [the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq) or Google support to get a clear statement on that topic.

Both, OSM and Google offer static map APIs that return stitched images, so you can combine them afterwards using a image processor. You can also use a GIS like QGIS to automate an script like:

- add OSM, GM, own layers
- tune styling
- export as static map

Hope this gives you an idea :)

Comment: I think I could use Google Maps Static API and dynamically blend it with my map layers by placing my layers in front of the google image and making it partially transparent. So long as the image is served by Google, it meets their requirement.

Unfortunately I cannot export it to PNG - which I need to do for print support. So I'll look into how Open Street Map can do this.